# iPhone Tab Bar Control Icon Problem

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, png-24

I have a problem using icons with the tab bar control and I don't know to fix.
The icons I'm using are png format 24*24.

They have a grey gradient background with a black shape in the middle.
The problem I have is that only the background gradient shows. The Black shape in the middle does not.

Have I Used the wrong format or something? I read in a book to use png format size 24*24

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a background on your icon.

The icons are designed to be used like an alpha mask and background will make it look like a filled square. 
Remove the gradient and use an image with an icon in the middle and a transparent background.

Comment: I am developer, so I have problem understanding what was the problem and solution. This was useful to me: http://greenerpastures.dk/blog/iphone-udvikling/how-to-make-tab-bar-icons